# Weights in Welch's t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, weighted-data

I am familiar with Welch's t-test, but I would like to use weighted means in the data. Is anyone familiar with a t-test with unequal variances, and how I can manually calculate a t-statistic and degrees of freedom?

I've found this:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/weights/docs/wtd.t.test but I don't see how he calculated everything.

How can I modify the t-statistic

$t \quad = \quad {\; \overline{X}_1 - \overline{X}_2 \; \over \sqrt{ \; {s_1^2 \over N_1} \; + \; {s_2^2 \over N_2} \quad }}$

and the Degrees of Freedom

$\nu \quad  \approx \quad 
 {{\left( \; {s_1^2 \over N_1} \; + \; {s_2^2 \over N_2} \; \right)^2 } \over
 { \quad {s_1^4 \over N_1^2 (N_1-1)} \; + \; {s_2^4 \over N_2^2 (N_2-1) } \quad }}$

so that the mean and standard deviation are weighted?

Comment: If this is in complex survey sampling context, this may be an open question from methodological perspective. The degrees of freedom / effective sample sizes are usually further reduced by unequal weights, but I am not aware of any papers that look at conflation of the two issues. (Although survey statisticians do not believe in equal variances, anyway.)